# Execute TableAdapter Queries that Inserts data

Tags: vb.net, insert

I'm trying to insert data into an access database using visual studio wizard .(vb.net)

the problem that when I try to build the update query then try it in the query builder it works good but when I try to develop the Code to Execute the query it doesn't effect the database Although no Error message appear , so i guess their is something wrong in my code although I'm trying to a code from a book I'm Studying from .... the code I'm trying is :

```
Dim SDTA As New UpdateWizardDataSetTableAdapters.StudentTableAdapter
SDTA.ClearBeforeFill = True
SDTA.InsertQuery(txtNameID.Text, txtName.Text)
MsgBox("Done")
```

Comment: Is `InsertQuery` the query to directly insert a student record? Have you used the debugger to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I already found the answer of my question the secret is to manually set the connection string of the table adapter.

SDTA.Connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""& _ application.startupbath&\UpdateWizard.accdb"

thanks For all who wanted to help